# Powershell to use regx to find character position

Tags: regex, powershell

I want to add " after third comma and " before fifth comma. How can this can be done  in powershell ?

My idea is to use regex function to find the location of the third and fifth comma then add " to them by

```
$s.Insert(4,'-') **In case reg return position 4
```

example data

```
04642583,3,HC Mobile,O213,Inc,SIS Services,KR,Non Payroll Relevant,KR50
```

Output

```
04642583,3,HC Mobile,"O213,Inc",SIS Services,KR,Non Payroll Relevant,KR50
```

This is code I tried, but it failed by 'An empty pipe element is not allowed' How to fix it

```
$source  = "D:\Output\MoreComma.csv"
$FinalFile = "D:\Output\MoreComma_Corrected.csv"

$content = Get-Content $source
foreach ($line in $content)
{
$items = $line.split(',');
$items[3] = '"'+$items[3]
$items[4] = $items[4]+'"';
$items -join ','
} | Set-Content $FinalFile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the format (e.g you know that it's always in this comma-separated fashion); and your're only trying to achieve this; you can simply just split the line, add the quotes and join the line again.

Example:

```
$data = "04642583,3,HC Mobile,O213,Inc,SIS Services,KR,Non Payroll Relevant,KR50";

$items = $data.split(',');
$items[3] = '"'+$items[3]
$items[4] = $items[4]+'"';
$items -join ','
```

This will produce the line:

```
04642583,3,HC Mobile,"O213,Inc",SIS Services,KR,Non Payroll Relevant,KR50
```

Given you've stored this in a CSV- file:

```
$file = "C:\tmp\test.csv";
$lines = (get-content $file);
$newLines=($lines|foreach-object {    
 $items = $_.split(',');
 $items[3] = '"'+$items[3]
 $items[4] = $items[4]+'"';
 $items -join ','
})
```

You can then output the result in a new file if you want

```
 $newLines|Set-content C:\tmp\test2.csv
```

This will "mess" up your CSV-format file though (as it will considered to "merge the columns"), but I'm guessing this is what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I tried to apply your code into my but it failed. Do you know how can i read it as file and then process it and output result as file?

Comment: Updated with example now reading from CSV and splitting and setting the result back in another file..

Comment: What do mean by 'This will "mess" up your CSV-format file though (as it will considered to "merge the columns"), but I'm guessing this is what you're trying to achieve?' ? I do this because it contain comma as data instead of delimiter